# Discussion/Talk page on Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, comments, answers

I've been seeing a lot of comments, on a lot of questions and answers, and most of them, seem to be related, some are asking new questions themselves, some are talking to the poster, looking for more information, but most of them seem to be more of discussion rather than comment.

But all these comments, are scattered, some are on the question itself, some are throughout all the different answers.

Would we benefit from having a separate Talk/Discussion page/tab/section that we could flesh out the details of the question, and ask more on, in one unified spot?

Also, it might be nice for questions that go unanswered, or the poster accepts a half-baked answer; so that people had a way of asking something like "hey did you ever figure this out" kind of deal and the poster still getting notifications on both sides.

I know it'd probably be difficult to get right, but maybe others have similar ideas on how to refine it, or something they'd like to see, or how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already have that: [Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: But as far as I'm aware (and maybe its my own limitation of knowledge here, chat isn't directly tied to questions?)

Comment: You can create a room and post the link to it in the question/comments.

Comment: I guess, I was just looking for something built-in, that didn't have to have a room created and linked, and require a rep-gate to go through, something as easy as comments. I just feel our current comments get too scattered, you'll have 5 or 6 comments sometimes about one answer on 3 different answers, or even the question itself. Or you get the question all muddied up with a bunch of comments asking more details, and have to unhide the actual, useful comments that answer the question/problem being addressed.

Comment: I think the mine reason why the system is limited in that regard is that questions should not need *extended* discussion. The main goal is to post a question and receive an answer. If the question needs extended discussion which would justify such features, then there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: Perhaps a way to automatically create a chat room for a question, and reflect the fact it exists and how much activity it contains on the question?  May not be a bad idea...

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Won't: Was that sarcasm? Because that's already happening if there are too many comments...but I think you know that.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: Would the discussion in the chat be available for others to read?

Comment: @Dor: Depends if it was private or not. Discussions which are directly transferred from the comments are limited to the two users (not sure if it can be made public, but I'd think so).